# Error converting varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT b.*,
       a.jeopCodeId,
       a.JeopCodeDetail
FROM   storm_jeopinfo     a,
       storm_orders       b
WHERE  a.ordernumber IS NOT NULL
       AND a.ordernumber = b.order_number
       AND b.Installed_dt IS NOT NULL
       AND b.CUST_SIGN_DT BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2012-06-01', 102) 
                              AND CONVERT(date, '2013-04-30', 102)
    UNION ALL
SELECT b.*,
       a.jeop_code,
       a.jeop_desc
FROM   storm_bpm_jeops     a,
       storm_orders        b
WHERE  b.order_number = a.Order_number
       AND b.srvc_order_unit = a.srvc_order_unit
```

> Error msg: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   'JEOP-008' to data type int.

It continues in the series with the next columns. Am unable to successfully execute this query.

Comment: In the first select you are selecting `a.jeopCodeId` and in the second one `a.jeop_code`. Are they the same data type?

Comment: It is a very poor programming technique to use implicit joins. Please read http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1367959865&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns to find out about this and other SQL antipatterns.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update you may want

CAST(SUBSTRING(a.jeop_code,6,3) as int) as jeopCodeId

or you may want a join like below.

However, I can't be sure unless you tell us what you want to do and the business rules of the table.

```
SELECT b.*,
       a.jeopCodeId,
       a.JeopCodeDetail,
       a2.jeop_code,
       a2.jeop_desc
FROM   storm_orders       b
       join storm_jeepinfo a on a.ordernumber = b.order_number
       join storm_bpm_jeops a2 on a2.order_number = b.order_number 
                     and a2.srvc_order_unit = b.srvc_order_unit
WHERE  a.ordernumber IS NOT NULL -- is b.ordernumber ever null if no then this can go.
       AND b.Installed_dt IS NOT NULL
       AND b.CUST_SIGN_DT BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2012-06-01', 102) 
                              AND CONVERT(date, '2013-04-30', 102)
```

Question: why does storm_jeepinfo.ordernumber not have an `_`?   Probably better if you were consistent in your naming.  This is the single most glaring novice mistake.

Bad naming does no one any good!

---

It looks like you have some typos.  Remember in a UNION ALL the select fields have to match exactly... so for example in the first select you select `a.jeopCodeId` but in the second you leave off the id and select `a.jeop_code` -- they are clearly not compatible data types.

I notice that A does not refer to the same table in both select statements.  It may be that some of the fields don't have compatible types.  In this case you can select empty strings `''` or `0` or even `null` for the fields you don't have which you are trying to union.

Comment: *In this case you can select empty strings '' or 0 or even null for the fields you don't have which you are trying to union.* You could always cast to a varchar

Comment: @ConradFrix - Sure, but I don't think that helps if you don't have the correct data.  Just casting things does not change the business rules that created them.

Comment: Well when you're substituting zeros, nulls, or empty strings to conform to a data type I think you've lost that battle.

Comment: @ConradFrix - No idea what you mean here... the context was doing a `UNION ALL` between tables that are different and only share some data.  Like selecting animals from a Cat table and a Fish table -- they could both have the "Name" field and the "Location" field, but the fish table won't have "#Legs" column.  Probably best to select `0` or `null` as a default in this case, not use the "#Fins" column.  (NB, This example was to illustrate, I'm not suggesting this DB has good design characteristics.)

Comment: You're not wrong, but my point is that sometimes it makes sense to union disparate data into a single column. Typically on search results or on reports. Having 4 columns where the data is exclusively in one pair or another may not be as useful as having a single pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*,
      cast (a.jeopCodeId as varchar (50)),
       a.JeopCodeDetail
FROM   storm_jeopinfo     a
JOIN       storm_orders       b
    ON a.ordernumber = b.order_number
WHERE  a.ordernumber IS NOT NULL
       AND b.Installed_dt IS NOT NULL
       AND b.CUST_SIGN_DT BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2012-06-01', 102) 
                              AND CONVERT(date, '2013-04-30', 102)
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*,
       a.jeop_code,
       a.jeop_desc
FROM   storm_bpm_jeops     a
JOIN       storm_orders        b
    ON  b.order_number = a.Order_number
       AND b.srvc_order_unit = a.srvc_order_unit
```

Note that I fixed the implicit joins which should not be used since they were replaced with better syntax (easier to maintain and less likely to have accidental cross joins) many years ago. Also, Select * is an extremely poor technique and should be replaced with a field list. This is especially true when you have a union as this will break if one table changes but not the other. Further it is wasteful of network and database resources to ever call more columns than you intend to use.